# Is there an automatic variable for all grouped targets in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Not seeing anything in documentation, but I could be missing something.  If I have:

```
a b &: c
    echo "targets are $???"
```

`$@` will only show `a` or `b`, but not both.   Is there anything that will expand to `a b`?

Comment: No, unfortunately.  That's not a bad idea though.  You could file an enhancement request on Savannah https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=make

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think you've missed anything as also pointed out in the comment. Behavior of `$@` is as specified / [documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Targets.html#Rules-with-Grouped-Targets):

> During the execution of a grouped target’s recipe, the automatic variable ‘$@’ is set to the name of the particular target in the group which triggered the rule.

Would using a variable be an acceptable solution to address your need?

```
GRP_1 := a b
$(GRP_1) &: c
        echo "targets are $(GRP_1)"
```